# Angle brackets in bfs java code

Tags: java

I am beginner to java and i have code for BFS algorithm.

What do the angle brackets mean?

```
Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>().
```

Comment: You may want to look up "Java Generics".

Comment: You might want to do some searching before asking in the future

Answer (score 0):

When Collections (like Queue) were first introduced in earlier versions of Java, they could only contain "Object".

Java 5 introduced ["generics"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html), which allowed you to declare a specific TYPE a collection contains (rather than just the "object" superclass).

That's what the angle brackets mean: a generic "Queue" containing type "Node".

Look here for more details:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html